# Node.js Express routing with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, routes, express, mongoose

Good afternoon,

I recently started working with Node.js + Express + MongoDB.
I set up a simple app containing :

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models = require('./models')
  , Document
  , db;

// lots of conf ...

models.defineModels(mongoose, function() {
  app.Document = Document = mongoose.model('Document');
  db = mongoose.connect(app.set('db-uri'));
})

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.home);
app.get('/documents.:format?', routes.list);

// classical end of app.js
```

I also have a corresponding 'index.js' file within a 'routes' folder, containing:

```
exports.home = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Indx' })
};

exports.list = function(req, res){
    Document.find().all(function(documents) {
        switch (req.params.format) {
            case 'json':
                res.send(documents.map(function(d) {
                    return d.__doc;
                }));
            break;
            default:
                res.render('index', { title: 'Indx' });
        }
    });
};
```

The routing part is OK, meaning that when I point my browser to localhost:3000, I see the (Jade-template generated) 'index' view. When I point to localhost:3000/documents, the routing works OK, and the code is trying to serve the 'list' part of my 'index.js' route. However, I was hoping that the 'Document' mongoose model I created in the main app would be recognized within 'index.js', but this is clearly not the case as I keep getting the following error :

```
Express
500 ReferenceError: Document is not defined
at C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\routes\index.js:23:2
at callbacks (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
at param (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
at param (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:243:11)
at pass (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:4)
at Object.handle (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10)
at next (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\http.js:204:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:35:5)
at next (C:\PERSO\DEV\indxjs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\http.js:204:15)
```

I could obviously define my routing from within the 'app.js' with something like :

```
app.get('/documents.:format?', loadUser, function(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

But can anyone see a way of talking with mongoose while retaining the elegant './routes/index.js' separation from the 'app.js' ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : following kind answer from Wes, I added the following code to 'index.js':

```
var Document;
function defineRoutes(mongoose, fn) {
  Document = mongoose.model('Document');
  fn();
}
exports.defineRoutes = defineRoutes;
// then the same as in initial post
```

And I enclosed the routing definitions within this function in 'app.js' :

```
routes.defineRoutes(mongoose, function() {
  app.get('/', routes.home);
  app.get('/documents.:format?', routes.list);
})
```

Everything is ok when I point to localhost:3000, but when I point to /documents, the browser keeps loading, loading ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Wes Johnson, I found my way out. I was blindly following a dated tutorial, which used deprecated methods from MongoDb. Below is the code snippet I finally used to implement the 'list documents' feature:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    Document.find({},function(err, documents) {
        switch (req.params.format) {
            case 'json':
                res.send(documents.map(function(d) {
                    return d.toObject();
                }));
            break;
            default:
                res.render('index', { title: 'Indx' });
        }
    });
};
```

Once again, thanks Wes !

Comment: Please, consider acepting this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Node modules are self-contained in terms of variable scope. Your `Document` object is not accessible from `index.js` as you mention. You need to pass this along to your routes logic, or pass along mongoose itself.

`require` calls are cached for the most part, so requiring mongoose in your `index.js` file and getting an instance of `Document` there is one option.

Since you don't really use `Document` in your `app.js`, you could always move the db configuration to another module and export the important references back to the scripts that need them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question following what I tried, but no luck ...

Comment: So you're not getting the `Document is not defined` error anymore? You shouldn't be. If the page never loads you're never hitting your response stream lines. At first glance it looks like there might be something wrong with your database call. I've never seen `.all` used in that manner... [here's what it's supposed to do](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all). If you're looking to get all the documents, just use [`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html).